# Appending DB Connection String with prepareSQL=0

Tags: sql

What does this do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming jTDS here:

"prepareSQL=0 is only intended for testing (as it actually replaces the parameter placeholders with string representations of the values and submits everything as a regular query) and it's also kind of beta. It should *never* be used in production.

Also, as you have seen, the performance penalty is quite severe compared to the other prepare modes."  (from [Eric Pugh's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dep4b/entry/java_sql_datatruncation_data_truncation)).